# Combine several Microsoft Exchange accounts into a single inbox in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2011

I have set up my Exchange accounts in Microsoft Outlook, but now I have a separate inbox for each and every account. Since it is annoying to constantly have to switch inboxes at work, I would rather have all my emails that I get from different accounts in one consolidated view. On my mobile, that works just fine, I even have one additional IMAP account, and it is presented together with the other Exchange accounts in the consolidated inbox.

For some reason, however, this does not seem to exist on my Outlook for Windows, or I have not been able to find it so far. I am required to use Outlook and can unfortunately not use any other mailing program.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Is this a work computer and accounts? Have you spoken with your IT staff? Have you tried Search Folders? A search folder would allow you to query all messages in folders called "Inbox" and display all of them in a single "folder" https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-search-folders-to-find-messages-or-other-outlook-items-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! But my Outlook only lets me look in the Outlook data files, so it does not display any messages for me in the search folders...?

Comment: As I asked earlier, is this a work computer and work accounts? Please add information to your original question as we ask these questions to clarify your issue. Use the EDIT button.

Comment: Only being able to search local data files doesn't make much sense. Unless you're in a business environment with certain policies enabled, Outlook will cache all content it loads from the remote mail sources in local files.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry. It's a private computer on which I use private and work accounts

Answer (score 2):

As I know, there seems to be no option that could combine multiple accounts' Inbox directly in Outlook, Search folder could only search these messages in a specific account. So in order to meet this this requirement in the future, we could vote for this [idea](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/11693799-unified-inbox-for-outlook-2016) about the Unified Inbox feature in uservoice for Outlook.

Also, based on my research,as an alternative, we could use the macro to query your Inbox automatically, for more detailed information about it, please refer to this article: [How to Create a Unified Inbox View](https://www.slipstick.com/how-to-outlook/how-to-create-a-unified-inbox/). Hope that could also be helpful to you.